# Socket.io access-control-allow=origin error from remote site

Tags: node.js, xmlhttprequest, remote-access, socket.io, access-control

I am trying to access a socket.io server from another site. It worked for a few weeks but now I keep getting the following error. It happens when accessing a server on nodester from a server on heroku. The error is:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://site2.nodester.com/socket.io/xhr-polling//1311008802545. 
Origin http://site1.heroku.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain.
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Here's how I'm connecting with the socket:

```
socket = new io.Socket(
    'site2.nodester.com', {port: 80, rememberTransport: false}
);
```

And here's the server code:

```
// requires

server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
    // server stuffs
}),

server.listen(8362);

var io = io.listen(server),

// io code
```

Comment: "Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain." Thats a problem too.

Comment: @JRPete I am facing the exact same problem and its driving me crazy! Were u able to find any solution for this?

Comment: refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34542759/1802348) post might you get a clue

Answer (score 5):

Did you [configure](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO) socket.io to still use default `origins = *` or at least put `origins =  site1.heroku.com`

Answer (score 4):

The problem I faced was, serving the client socket.io.js from a different location.

You can avoid this issue by serving the client js file from the same server where you are trying to connect to.

for example, my initial client code was this and it was throwing error

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
var socket = io.connect('http://mydomain.com/');
```

once I modified it to this, it worked alright.

```
<script src="http://mydomain.com/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
var socket = io.connect('http://mydomain.com/');
```

And my server code is,

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        next();
    });
var server = http.createServer(app);
io = socketio.listen(server, {log:false, origins:'*:*'});
... //io.connect and events below
```

Comment: You can also proxy this with Nginx (http://michieldemey.be/blog/proxying-websockets-with-nginx-and-socket-io/) so you can have nginx in the same domain and socket.io somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

I've a same problem and I don't arrive at resolved.

I test many configuration:

```
  io.set("origins","*");
  io.set('transports', [
    'websocket'
  , 'flashsocket'
  , 'htmlfile'
  , 'xhr-polling'
  , 'jsonp-polling'
  ]);
```

or

```
  io.set("origins = *");
  io.set('transports', [
    'websocket'
  , 'flashsocket'
  , 'htmlfile'
  , 'xhr-polling'
  , 'jsonp-polling'
  ]);
```

or

```
var socket  = io.listen(appS1,{origins: '*:*'});
```

thanks your help :)

Comment: Vsplit, what version of socket.io worked for you? I'm currently having this problem.

Comment: I'm using socket.io 0.9.0 and even after setting origins to *:*, I am having this problem. XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://undefined/socket.io/1/?t=1332151750943. Origin http://localhost:8989 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: @user644745 I am facing the exact same problem and its driving me crazy! Were u able to find any solution for this?

Comment: @Bitsian did you ever find the solution? Still facing the same issue here.

Comment: @Mahn Have posted my answer ! It was a long time back , but I have posted the settings I have in my socket.io file and it definitely worked for me!!

Comment: @Bitsian thanks! this didn't seem to work for me last time but I'll try again.

Answer (score 3):

It might be not exactly related, but could eventually help some poor souls on this issue:

I've just encountered that running the client from local disk (at least on Windows) eg. `file:///c:/...` results in a "null" origin, which will crash the origins check. Try uploading the client to a remote website and fire it from there. Leave the origins on *:*.

Hope this helps some people out.

Comment: Same problem for me. I was trying to connect to server using `socket.io`, and it only works when I put the file on a server rather then disk. But I really want to load it as  a local file in Chrome, is there any other solution?

Comment: Post is long dead but for future reference you could have used a WAMP Stack installation or something similar to host it at http://localhost/ or similar instead of loading up a file.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me

```
var app = require('express')()
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , sio = require('socket.io');     

var io = sio.listen(server, { origins: '*:*' });
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by loading the client's socket.io.js from the server itself, rather than maintaining a local copy on the site. In my setup, there is a webpage on a certain website that fetches the file from the server, which is at a different location.

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround (thanks to [mattcodez](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/1046#issuecomment-10138457)):

`io = io.listen(8888);
io.server.removeListener('request', io.server.listeners('request')[0]);`

There is an open bug for this issue and you can read more about it [here](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/1046):

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing one line of client code.

I changed

```
var socket = io('localhost');
```

to

```
var socket = io();
```