# The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' error in laravel-echo-server

Tags: php, laravel, sockets, socket.io

To make real time an laravel app I want to use socket-io.

Client is an mobile App written by ionic framework and ran at `192.168.1.7:8100`.

To configure and run socket-io Server I installed `[laravel-echo-server][1]`.

This is larvel echo server configuration file to run socket io server :

```
{
    "authHost": "http://api.pars-app.dev",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [
        {
            "appId": "1924bf1d59b3759d",
            "key": "keykeykey"
        }
    ],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {},
        "sqlite": {
            "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        }
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": null,
    "port": "3000",
    "protocol": "http",
    "socketio": {},
    "sslCertPath": "",
    "sslKeyPath": ""
}
```

First I run redis server with this command :

```
redis-server --port 3001
```

Then used this command to run soketio server :

```
laravel-echo-server start
```

result is like this :

```
L A R A V E L  E C H O  S E R V E R

version 1.2.7

⚠ Starting server in DEV mode...

✔  Running at localhost on port 3000
✔  Channels are ready.
✔  Listening for http events...
✔  Listening for redis events...

Server ready!
```

And this is  Echo laravel js :

```
window.echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: 'http://192.168.1.7:3000',
    auth: {
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjUsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL2FwaS5wYXJzLWFwcC5kZXZcL3YxXC9hdXRoXC9zaWduSW4iLCJpYXQiOjE0OTI2NzU3OTgsImV4cCI6MTQ5NTI2Nzc5OCwibmJmIjoxNDkyNjc1Nzk4LCJqdGkiOiI5OTE3YTA4OWY0MDI4NjMwOTU5NWZmYjZmODQ2MTk5ZSJ9.oOFRmxQoiLS8BJksPkf6CQSVOcDR7rPApS71S6nZO5c'
        }
    }
});
```

But When I run main App in **Chrome** browser got below error in console :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.1.7:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LkQ5Rnb. The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'http://192.168.1.7:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

I tried many solution to solve this problem like [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23995077/498504) but problem is continued.

Comment: did you find any solution for this...?

Comment: No yet.........

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use virtual host replace for IP address?

And configure like this

```
ServerName your-domain.dev

DocumentRoot /var/www/html/your_project/public

<Directory "/var/www/html/your_project/public">
       AllowOverride all
       Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
       Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT, PATCH"
       Header set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
       Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept"
</Directory>
```

And running SocketIO listen and call to your domain.

Hope this help. I already using SocketIO for my project.

I'm using PM2 for run SocketIO.

Comment: I tried your solution but after adding `<Directory "/var/www/html/your_project/public">` tag to `httpd-vhost.conf` and restarting wamp, wamp icon remained orange

Comment: @A.B.Developer Did you enable vhost configure? By uncomment LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so in `httpd.conf` file?

Comment: Yes ,I followed https://john-dugan.com/wamp-vhost-setup/ instruction to create a virtual host

Comment: @A.B.Developer Did you change hosts file? Can you try to ping to your-domain?

Comment: I found that problem is for `Header set Access-Control-...` commands where if I comment all of them , wamp runs successfully.

Comment: Also I could ping to that domain

Comment: @A.B.Developer Can you check your module header already enable or not bro? In apache2 we can: `sudo a2enmode headers`

Comment: first it was disabled then I enabled it. but problem is continued. Furthermore when I want to access to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` it shows `You don't have permission to access / on this server.` error